# How could I use update statement using <if> statement on MyBatis

Tags: mysql, if-statement, mybatis, ibatis

I want to know how to use if statement like below case

```
<update id="update"
    parameterType="com.MyClass">
    UPDATE
        Board SET Status = 1
    <where>
        <if test="A != null and A.length() > 0">AND A = ${A}</if>
    </where>
</update>
```

This statement works when A!=null and A.length() > 0.

But if A==null, then update whole rows set 1 cause there is no where conditions.

Is there any way to update if there is proper condition, otherwise skip or ignore?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<update id="update"
    parameterType="com.MyClass">
    UPDATE
        Board SET Status = 1
    <where>
        <choose>
            <when test="A != null and A.length() > 0">
                 AND A = ${A}
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                 AND 0 = 1
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </where>
</update>
```

With condition 0 = 1 the where fails and no updates are done

Comment: Well, thanks!
This is what i think. Is there anyway except 0 = 1?
I want to make statement clean :(

Comment: you have to make the where false, so an option could be: AND FALSE. I prefer 0 = 1, but it's your choice... If I helped you, please, mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

`<update id="update"
    parameterType="com.MyClass">
    UPDATE
        Board SET Status = 1
    <where>
        <![CDATA[<if test="A != null and A.length() > 0">AND A = ${A}</if>]]>
    </where>
</update>`

It would be nice to try CDATA